# String.replaceAll() and Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to search a bunch of lines of text and replace the first word in the sentence with a bolded version of that word. What I thought was the appropriate code isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
String s;
s.replaceAll("^(.+)\\B", "<b>\\1</b>")
```

I'm wondering if this is even the proper approach, because my string is one ling HTML string with each line ending in `<br>`.. so there's really only one "line". Not sure how to accomplish this given this insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable!!

```
s = s.replaceAll("^(.+)\\B", "<b>\\1</b>");
```

---

Oh, and you should use `$0` to refer to the match as opposed to `\\1`.

Comment: The big issue that I'm noticing is that the matches are getting replaced by the number 1, instead of \\1 actually referencing the match.

Comment: This ended up being the case. $1 actually properly referenced the captured group. Thanks. Not sure why the official documentation on Oracle's site said to use \\1.

Comment: Oh, hmm, yea that is strange. Anyway, glad I could help :-)